# JavaScript regex replace last pattern in string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string which looks like

```
var std = new Bammer({mode:"deg"}).bam(0, 112).bam(177.58, (line-4)/2).bam(0, -42)
  .ramBam(8.1, 0).bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)
```

I want to put a tag around the last `.bam()` or `.ramBam()`.

```
str.replace(/(\.(ram)?bam\(.*?\))$/i, '<span class="focus">$1</span>');
```

And I hope to get:

```
new Bammer({mode:"deg"}).bam(0, 112).bam(177.58, (line-4)/2).bam(0, -42).ramBam(8.1, 0)<span class="focus">.bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)</span>
```

But somehow I keep on fighting with the non greedy parameter, it wraps everything after new Bammer with the span tags. Also tried a questionmark after before the `$` to make the group non greedy.

I was hoping to do this easy, and with the `bam` or `ramBam` I thought that regex would be the easiest solution but I think I'm wrong.

Where do I go wrong?

Comment: do you want to include the (number, number) in the tag around .bam and .ramBam?

Comment: @FujiRoyale yes, in fact there maybe nested params in there.

Comment: There is a bit of a catch to this question which I omitted to mention is that there maybe nested params ie: `ram(0,(slotheight-5)/2)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following regex:

```
(?!.*\)\.)(\.(?:bam|ramBam)\(.*\))$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ArnuaH/9)

```
(?!.*\)\.)         # do not match ').' later in the string
(                  # begin capture group 1                   
  .\               # match '.'
  (?:bam|ramBam)   # match 'bam' or 'ramBam' in non-cap group
  \(.*\)           # match '(', 0+ chars, ')'
)                  # end capture group 1
$                  # match end of line
```

For the example given in the question the negative lookahead `(?!.*\)\.)` moves an internal pointer to just before the substring:

```
.bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)
```

as that is the first location where there is no substring `).` later in the string.

If there were no end-of-line anchor `$` and the string ended:

```
...0).bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)abc
```

then the substitution would still be made, resulting in a string that ends:

```
...0)<span class="focus">.bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)</span>abc
```

Including the end-of-line anchor prevents the substitution if the string does not end with the contents of the intended capture group.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, and contributions to the previous answer. My apologies for letting out the requirement of nested parameters. Booboo's answer also covers that, so I will make that the accepted answer for now.

Answer (score 2):

Regex to use:

```
/\.((?:ram)?[bB]am\([^)]*\))(?!.*\.(ram)?[bB]am\()/
```

1. `\.` Matches period.
2. `(?:ram)?` Optionally matches `ram` in a *non-capturing* group.
3. `[bB]am` Matches `bam` or `Bam`.
4. `\(` Matches `(`.
5. `[^)]*` Matches 0 or more characters as long as they are not a `)`.
6. `)` Matches a `)`. Items 2. through 6. are placed in Capture Group 1.
7. `(?!.*\.(ram)?[bB]am\()` This is a negative lookahead assertion stating that the rest of the string contains no further instance of `.ram(` or `.rambam(` or `.ramBam(` and therefore this is the last instance.

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/OqEDDU/4/)

```js
let str = 'var std = new Bammer({mode:"deg"}).bam(0, 112).bam(177.58, 0).bam(0, -42).ramBam(8.1, 0).bam(8.1, slot_height)';
console.log(str.replace(/\.((?:ram)?[bB]am\([^)]*\))(?!.*\.(ram)?[bB]am\()/, '<span class="focus">.$1</span>'));
```

**Update**

The JavaScript regular expression engine is not powerful enough to handle nested parentheses. The only way I know of solving this is if we can make the assumption that after the final call to `bam` or `ramBam` there are no more extraneous right parentheses in the string. Then where I had been scanning the parenthesized expression with `\([^)]*\)`, which would fail to pick up final parentheses, we must now use `\(.*\)` to scan everything until the final parentheses. At least I know no other way. But that also means that the way that I had been using to determine the final instance of `ram` or `ramBam` by using a negative lookahead needs a slight adjustment. I need to make sure that I have the final instance of `ram` or `ramBam` *before* I start doing any greedy matches:

```
(\.(?:bam|ramBam)(?!.*\.(bam|ramBam)\()\((.*)\))
```

[See Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tZd2b6/3/)

1. `\.` Matches `.`.
2. `(?:bam|ramBam)` Matches bam or ramBam.
3. `(?!.*\.(bam|ramBam)\()` Asserts that Item 1. was the final instance
4. `\(` Matches `(`.
5. `(.*)` Greedily matches everything until ...
6. `\)` the final `)`.
7. `)` Items 1. through 6. are placed in Capture Group 1.

```js
let str = 'var std = new Bammer({mode:"deg"}).bam(0, 112).bam(177.58, (line-4)/2).bam(0, -42) .ramBam(8.1, 0).bam(8.1, (slot_height-thick)/2)';
console.log(str.replace(/(\.(?:bam|ramBam)(?!.*\.(bam|ramBam)\()\((.*)\))/, '<span class="focus">$1</span>'));
```

Comment: @CarySwoveland Of course, now  `(?:ram|ramBam)` seems so more logical. Oh well.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, there is small catch however: there maybe nested params in the string. Which does exclude the last `)` from the match. For now I will revert to `str.substring`, `str.lastIndexOf` juggling.

Answer (score 1):

The non-greedy flag isn't quite right here, as that will just make the regex select the minimal number of characters to fit the pattern. I'd suggest that you do something with a [negative lookahead](https://javascript.info/regexp-lookahead-lookbehind) like this:

```js
str.replace(/(\.(?:ram)?[Bb]am\([^)]*\)(?!.*(ram)?[Bb]am))/i, '<span class="focus">$1</span>');
```

Note that this will only replace the *last* function name (`bam` OR `ramBam`), but not both. You'd need to take a slightly different approach to be able to replace both of them.